# Make custom RisedButton expand

Tags: flutter, button, width

i am new to flutter and building custom RisedButton
I have this button

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EasyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final onPressed;
  final text;
  EasyButton(this.onPressed, this.text);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: this.onPressed,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      elevation: 2,
      splashColor: Colors.blue[300],
      child: Ink(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
          gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blue[800]],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
        child: new Text(this.text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But i when i am using it with Expanded widget i get this result

[image]

How can I make it 100% parent width expanded?

With double.infinity

[image]

With container

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the RaisedButton inside ButtonTheme and specify minWidth.

```
ButtonTheme(
 minWidth: double.infinty, //takes up all the width 
 child: RaisedButton(), 
)
```

Comment: Then i have grey area becomes invisible but clickable and gradient stretches same as text length.

Comment: made a change, pls update your code and let us know

Comment: Thanks. Now whole grey area became blue. Please look at the screenshot in original question. Still not desired look.

Comment: It worked fine on my side maybe some other properties are hindering your desired look. Try removing padding and play with other properties..

Comment: It streteches but not gradient. If i remove gradient all button looks blue. It looks like only gradient is that width. There are not much paddings to play around :(

Comment: I ended up with child: Container(
                  height: 35,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    this.text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )), But i do no tlike height prperty. It would be nice height expands also to size of button. Because without height it looks like - for image please look at original question